# Show progress bar while downloading excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-3.5

We are getting some time to download excel on button click, while in middle of that we want to show progress bar

Can anyone please help me

we have following code on button click and export excel code

protected void ibtnExport_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

```
        if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 0)
        {
            ds = (DataSet)ViewState["DSCurrResponseSummary"];

            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                 string ColName = "DOMAIN,PERIOD,CIRCLE,DEPARTMENT,SUB-DEPARTMENT,UNIT,ASSESSMENT NUMBER,ASSESSMENTNAME,TOTAL,PENDING,RESPONDED CONTROL,COMPLIANT,NON COMPLIANT,NOT APPLICABLE,TOTAL RESPONDENTS,STATUS,TARGET CLOSURE DATE,REVIEWED";
                string strBindCols = "DOMAIN_NAME,PERIOD_NAME,CIRCLE_NAME,DEPARTMENT_NAME,SUBDEPARTMENT_NAME,UNIT_NAME,ASSESMENT_NO,ASSESMENT_NAME,TOTAL_RESPONSE,PENDING_RESPONSE,RESPONDED_CONTROL,COMPLIANT,NON_COMPLIANT,Non Applicable,Total Respondant,STATUS,RESPONSE_DUE_DATE,IS_REVIEWED";

                DataTable Exportdt = ds.Tables[2];
                ExportToExcelFunction("Current Assessment Response Summary", Exportdt, ColName, strBindCols);

            }
        }
        else if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 1)
        {
            ds = (DataSet)ViewState["DSPastResponseSummary"];

            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                string ColName = "DOMAIN,PERIOD,CIRCLE,DEPARTMENT,SUB-DEPARTMENT,UNIT,ASSESSMENT NUMBER,ASSESSMENTNAME,TOTAL,PENDING,RESPONDED CONTROL,COMPLIANT,NON COMPLIANT,NOT APPLICABLE,TOTAL RESPONDENTS,STATUS,TARGET CLOSURE DATE,REVIEWED";
                string strBindCols = "DOMAIN_NAME,PERIOD_NAME,CIRCLE_NAME,DEPARTMENT_NAME,SUBDEPARTMENT_NAME,UNIT_NAME,ASSESMENT_NO,ASSESMENT_NAME,TOTAL_RESPONSE,PENDING_RESPONSE,RESPONDED_CONTROL,COMPLIANT,NON_COMPLIANT,Non Applicable,Total Respondant,STATUS,RESPONSE_DUE_DATE,IS_REVIEWED";

                DataTable Exportdt = ds.Tables[3];
                ExportToExcelFunction("Past Assessment Response Summary", Exportdt, ColName, strBindCols);

            }
        }
            //if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            //{

            //    //string ColName = "DOMAIN,PERIOD,CIRCLE,DEPARTMENT,SUB-DEPARTMENT,UNIT,ASSESSMENT NUMBER,ASSESSMENTNAME,STATUS";
            //    //string strBindCols = "DOMAIN_NAME,PERIOD_NAME,CIRCLE_NAME,DEPARTMENT_NAME,SUBDEPARTMENT_NAME,UNIT_NAME,ASSESMENT_NO,ASSESMENT_NAME,STATUS";
            //    string ColName = "DOMAIN,PERIOD,CIRCLE,DEPARTMENT,SUB-DEPARTMENT,UNIT,ASSESSMENT NUMBER,ASSESSMENTNAME,TOTAL,PENDING,STATUS";
            //    string strBindCols = "DOMAIN_NAME,PERIOD_NAME,CIRCLE_NAME,DEPARTMENT_NAME,SUBDEPARTMENT_NAME,UNIT_NAME,ASSESMENT_NO,ASSESMENT_NAME,TOTAL_RESPONSE,PENDING_RESPONSE,STATUS";

            //    DataTable Exportdt = ds.Tables[0];
            //    ExportToExcelFunction("Assessment Response Summary", Exportdt, ColName, strBindCols);

            //}

        Response.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

public void ExportToExcelFunction(string FlName, DataTable mydt, string DispColName, string BindCols)
{
    Excel.Application xlObj = new Excel.Application();
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlObj.Visible = false;
    //vinod
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("Export");
    string strFlName = filepath + "\\Master.xlsx";

    Excel.Workbook xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(strFlName, 0, true, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, true, 0, true);
    Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWB.ActiveSheet;

    int cols = mydt.Columns.Count;
    int rows = mydt.Rows.Count;

    //Added for export to excel
    try
    {
        //For Column
        string[] strCols = DispColName.Split(',');
        for (int i = 1; i <= strCols.Length; i++)
        {
            if (strCols[i - 1].Length > 0 && strCols[i - 1] != null)
                xlSheet.Cells[1, i] = Convert.ToString(strCols[i - 1]);
        }

        // for Row   
        string[] strColBind = BindCols.Split(',');
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < strColBind.Length; c++)
            {
                if (mydt.Rows[r][strColBind[c]].ToString().ToUpper() == "RELEASED")
                    xlSheet.Cells[r + 2, c + 1] = "OPEN";
                else
                    xlSheet.Cells[r + 2, c + 1] = mydt.Rows[r][strColBind[c]];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }


    String newFlName = "\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "_" + FlName + ".xls";
    xlWB.SaveAs(filepath + newFlName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, "", "", false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, true, false, "", true);

    xlWB.Close(true, oMissing, oMissing);
    xlObj.Quit();

    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"" + filepath + newFlName + "");
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + FlName + ".xls");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/download";
    Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Response.End();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Progress Bar, you have to include following code:-

Make sure, that you have any image which shown on this div

```
<div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br />
    <br />
    <img src="loader.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

**Modal background CSS**
You will need to place the following CSS in HEAD section of page for modal background

```
<style type="text/css">
    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .loading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>
```

**Add Jquery to show Progress Bar**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
</script>
```

**On Page Load** add below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=btnSubmit]').click(); });";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
    }
}
```

Refer http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-progress-bar-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx

Make some changes related to your control name in above sample code.

Comment: Hi Piyush, Its works ,but progess bar not ending after file dowload.We need to restart application. Can you help me in that ....